# Have answers been removed from this question?

Tags: support, deleted-answer

If I remember correctly, there used to be three answers to my question, [*Do I need a special cable for this SSD?*](https://superuser.com/questions/1777260/do-i-need-a-special-cable-for-this-ssd). One answer was bad and was downvoted. The other two were similar to each other and both helpful, and I believe I had accepted one.

Looking back now, I see only one answer. It is one of the helpful ones, but it is not accepted.

So unless my memory is completely wrong, two answers have been deleted from this question, including the one that I accepted.

Two questions:

- If my memory is correct and there were three answers, why have two of them been deleted, including the one I accepted?
- Is there a way to check the answer deletion history of a question without having to come here to *Meta*?

Comment: You can get 10k reputation to see deleted posts, but that's quite a bit more work than asking politely on meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was only one other answer, and it was [deleted by the community from the review queue](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/1181815).

There is/was no third answer. Perhaps you are thinking of a comment. There is indeed a comment posted by the same person who wrote the answer that was deleted that says exactly the same. Presumably they deleted their comment on copying it to an answer.

Six people saw that answer and every one of them thought it low quality enough that they all recommended it be deleted. At least four people, not necessarily those who reviewed it, also felt that it deserved a downvote as well.

I suspect that it was felt to be low quality because it does not explain *what* kind of USB cable you need and *why* one cable might be better than another. USB C is a connector type, it tells you nothing about what the cable behind that connector actually supports. What makes one "known good" is also very vague.

[image]

Viewing deleted posts [requires 10,000 reputation on the site](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Until you get that reputation you will have to ask a moderator or another high reputation user to look for you. There is a [list of all the site privileges you can earn](https://superuser.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. As for the answer I thought I had accepted, I see that it was another recent question that had two similar, helpful answers, of which I accepted one (https://superuser.com/questions/1775876/is-there-a-risk-installing-win10-printer-driver-in-win11). So my memory was indeed wrong about that being the case on the USB question. I'm now going to go back and accept the one answer remaining on that question.

Comment: @Mokubai - "Presumably they deleted their comment on copying it to a comment." - I think you mean "copying it to an answer".

Comment: As for the answer that was deleted. It's literally two sentences.  Both should be considered comments.  The fact the author originally submitted them as a comment should tell you most everything you need to know as to the reason every single reviewer voted to deleted the answer. So their answer suggested that, using any good USB 3.2 Type-C should work, but it wasn't working for you.  Additionally, USB 3.2 Type-C cables, are not all created equal. What further complicates things is the fact, USB Type-C cables, can support USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 (USB 3.2 Gen 1).

Comment: USB 3.2 Gen 1 and USB 3.2 Gen 2 are not the same thing.  There is a massive gap between the theoretical and realized transfer speeds of USB 3.2 Gen 1 and USB 3.2 Gen 2.